# FB Graph - Can only access 'home' connection for current user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i just wrote a home viewer in asp.net for my facebook profile. But what i really wanted was a page that shows the wall from my facebook page. But now i get this error:

"You can only access the \"home\" connection for the current user."

Does this mean that it is imposible to use the graph api to show everything that's written on an certain page?

Or how should i request these posts and comments on my facebook page wall?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is driving me mad too.

If you:

1. Sign into Facebook in your browser, and then use Facebook as page.
2. Then go into http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/
3. Then click on the News feed: https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=... link
4. Voila, there is your correct news feed for your page.

So, in theory this can work. i.e. The graph API does support it.

However, if I switch to the page, then try and sign in using https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize

It now tells me that I must switch from using Facebook as my page to using it as myself.

Therefore, the issue is likely to do with the graph oauth authorize, which doesn't seem to like you signing in as a page.

I suspect that I might be able to go searching through the cookies and find a token that means I don't need to login using the graph authorisation. I will continue down this path.

If anyone else has come up with a method to get the 'home' feed for a page then please contribute!

Edit: The answer is that there is no answer. I would say this is an oversight on FBs part. Hopefully they add it in the future. Bummer!

NOTE: I did also try using the old rest API with the token that you can get using the me/accounts graph call that gives you impersonated page access, but this results in an "impersonated access tokens can only be used with the Graph API" error message.

Comment: you know you can sign in as page? graph.facebook.com/me/accounts&access_token=xxx will show you every page or app you administrate. Grab your access_token for the page you want to use. I tried home with this access token but still no result. Except if was somewhere wrong ...

Comment: Yes, sorry I wasn't so clear enough. In the NOTE above, this is how I got the token for impersonated page access. I have absolutely everything working but 'home'. Because it doesn't work. But you know FB, it may suddenly work at some stage in the future and we will find it by accident :-)

Answer (score 0):

you have to add the

> manage_pages

scope with your authorize request, since some time. Maybe this will help you. Did you do that?