# Posting photo to facebook page

Tags: c#, facebook-c#-sdk, photo, access-token

I'm working on posting to facebook pages using the C# SDK. I can post updates and links fine but when I try to add a photo I get the following error

"(190) Impersonated access tokens can only be used with the Graph API"

When I change the access token to the user's the photo gets uploaded to the users profile and not the page.

Anyone know what's going wrong here and how to fix it?

Comment: maybe this can be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6041364/11343

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your full scenario, but https://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com supports this easily with the New-FBPhoto and New-FBFeed commands.

Answer (score 0):

You must be using a page access token. You need to use the user's access token with manage_page permissions and target the page id.